# How do you summarize another column in a progressive way?

Tags: vba, excel

Ok this is what I tried with:

```
Sheets("ProDiver ored").Range("X" & i).Value = Sheets("ProDiver ored").Range("W2:W" + i).Value
```

But it doesn't work.

What I am trying to do is to make the macro take the `W1:Wx` and summarize these on the X column.

It should be looking like this in other words:

```
X1 = W1 

X2 = W1 + W2

X3 = W1 + W2 + W3

X4 = W1 + W2 + W3 + W4
```

And so on.

Can you guys direct me on how to do this? I want it for a VBA Excel macro of course.

Comment: Have added as a comment as not a VBA solution - you could use this formula **=SUM($W$1:$W1)** entered in cell X1 and dragged down.  The second row reference is relative so will increase as you drag down - **=SUM($W$1:$W2)** in cell X2 for example.

Comment: The above is a valid answer @DarrenBartrup-Cook :) You should post it as an answer

Comment: Based on @DarrenBartrup-Cook comment, this is the shortest possible way to achieve the same in VBA. `Sheets("ProDiver ored").Range("X1:X10").Formula = "=SUM($W$1:$W1)"` Replace `X1:X10` with the relevant range

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 1):

As Siddharth suggested (and slightly changed from the comment):

This will paste the formula from X1 down to the bottom of the data range:

```
Sub JustFormula()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range(.Cells(1, 24), .Cells(Rows.Count, 23).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).Formula = "=SUM($W$1:$W1)"
    End With
End Sub
```

A slight change to the procedure and you can have just the values instead:

```
Sub JustValues()

    Dim MyRange As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set MyRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 24), .Cells(Rows.Count, 23).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1))
    End With

    MyRange.Formula = "=SUM($W$1:$W1)"
    MyRange.Value = MyRange.Value

End Sub
```

If your workbook takes a while to calculate you may want to put a DoEvents before the .Value = .Value line.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sheets("ProDiver ored").Range("X" & i).Value = Application.Sum(Sheets("ProDiver ored").Range("W1:W" & i))
```

above assumes you do not need the formula to add values up just the result of the calculation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all sub parts of the concatenation like in your example, you should have a loop: (untested!)

```
Dim cell As Object
Dim j As Integer
Dim newString As String
Set newString = ""
Set j = 0
For cell in Sheets("ProDiver ored").Range("W:W") 'entire column W
    newString = newString + cell.Value
    Range("X" & j).Value = newString
    j = j + 1
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. I already tested it. It work well.

```
Public Sub summarizeValue()

    Dim row As Integer
    Dim summarize As Integer
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet

    'Set start row
    row = 1

    'Getting data sheet
    Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheetname")

    'We need some break point, so I used "Do While" instead of "For" which is looping all cell.
    'Loop column cells until blank
    Do While dataSheet.Range("W" & row) <> ""

        'If adding integer, use "+" sign
        'If adding string, use "&" sign
        summarize = summarize + dataSheet.Range("W" & row)

        'Set summarize value into result cell
        dataSheet.Range("X" & row) = summarize

        'Increase row
        row = row + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```